# aligning math equations in Latex

Tags: latex, amsmath

I am trying to align the following equations around the equal sign. What can I do? Thanks! I am using the AMSMath package

```
    $$m\ddot{x}_{1}-K(x_{2}+x_{12})+C(\dot{x}_{12}+\dot{x}_{2})+2C\dot{x}_{1} = fx_{1}$$
$$m\ddot{x}_{2}-K(x_{3}+x_{1})+C(\dot{x}_{1}+\dot{x}_{3})+2C\dot{x}_{2} = fx_{2}$$ 
$$m\ddot{x}_{3}-K(x_{4}+x_{2})+C(\dot{x}_{2}+\dot{x}_{4})+2C\dot{x}_{3} = fx_{3}$$
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138840/164376) before voting to migrate this to tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\begin{align}
    m\ddot{x}_{1}-K(x_{2}+x_{12})+C(\dot{x}_{12}+\dot{x}_{2})+2C\dot{x}_{1} &= fx_{1} \\
    m\ddot{x}_{2}-K(x_{3}+x_{1})+C(\dot{x}_{1}+\dot{x}_{3})+2C\dot{x}_{2} &= fx_{2} \\
    m\ddot{x}_{3}-K(x_{4}+x_{2})+C(\dot{x}_{2}+\dot{x}_{4})+2C\dot{x}_{3} &= fx_{3}
\end{align}
```

See the [user's guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

To make a long story short... the following idea of using `eqnarray` is kind of obvious, but turns out to be a **really bad idea**. `eqnarray` brings lots of issues which are solved in `amsmath` and related packages. Read [Lars Madsen: Avoid eqnarray](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) for the details.

```
\begin{eqnarray*} %% Do avoid eqnarray if possible.
    x_1 & = & 1 \\
    x_2 & = & 2 \\
    x_3 & = & 3
\end{eqnarray*}
```

(Answer revised with information from [Arthur Reutenauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46495/arthur-reutenauer), [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) and the Madsen paper linked to by Thomas.)

Comment: Not really smart: eqnarray is *really* outdated (since 15 years or so).  The AMS environment are a much safer choice.

Comment: I won't downvote you for this, but know for once and for all that eqnarray is evil: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf

Comment: I don't think eqnarray is that bad, but I appreciate the link to the article explaining why people prefer the amsmath alternative.

Comment: @ndim: Thanks for taking our comments into account!  I, too, started with eqnarray ten years ago, and then I read the LaTeX companion...

Comment: @Arthur: I was not aware that so much had changed since that time in the 1990s when I read my first book on LaTeX, so eqnarray seemed obvious. Apparently though, I am not the only one who is prone to falling into that trap, so I guess it is a good idea to leave this answer here. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 4):

There are several packages to do what you want, one of the most widely used is the AMS' `align` environment from the `amsmath` package.

Simplified extract from amsldoc.pdf:

```
\begin{align} 
x&=y \\ 
x’&=y’ \\ 
x+x’&=y+y’ 
\end{align}
```

The equations are aligned around the symbols that follow `&` (the equals signs, in this case).